# price box in a short code inside them

Tags: wordpress, loops

i wanted to ask if their's any possibility to make a loop to a p inside the_content() for making every line in a different color?

for making a price column ....

```
<div
    class="pricing-plan zero-margin <?php echo $style_class . ($last_column ? ' last' : '') . (!empty($highlight) ? ' highlight' : ''); ?>">
    <div class="top-header">
        <h3 class="center"><?php the_title() ?></h3>
        <?php if (!empty($tagline))
            echo '<p class="tagline center">' . $tagline . '</p>'; ?>
        <?php if (!empty($pricing_img_url))
            echo '<img alt="' . get_the_title() . '" src="' . $pricing_img_url . '" /><br>'; ?>
            <p class="plan-price plan-header center"><span class="button-price-plan"><?php echo $price_tag ?></span></p>
    </div>                     
    <div class="plan-details">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- .plan-details -->
    <div class="purchase">
        <a class="button default" href="<?php echo $pricing_url; ?>"
           target="_self"><?php echo $pricing_button_text; ?></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML that is being output from the_content()? This sounds more like a CSS issue than a loop issue. Please add the HTML output from your shortcode.

Comment: i want it to loop so with two colors and thats that
and to work with all the browsers
i css i had used the :nth-child(odd/even)but it wont work every where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to add different style to each

tag of your content.You cant loop through the content

tag.
You can do it using css

```
p:nth-child(2)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

For more details about css nth-child selector you can visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: Great thanks i tried it and it works :-) can you send me a loop of this for all the browsers?

Comment: This is a css code you need to select paragraph manually with the selector`p:nth-child(2) or p:nth-child(3) or p:nth-child(4)` etc.Visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) for more info